# max() function in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a derived column from existing columns in my dataframe.
The line of code looks like this:

```
df['New_Column'] = (df['Column1']-df['Column2'])/max(df['Column2'], 5)
```

Obviously, this returns an error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

This is because the max() function is comparing "5" with all values of the series, rather than each specific value and "5".

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Please post sample input with expected output for better understanding.

Comment: it is `df['column2'].max()`not the way you have it written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` is a Python function and only accept one single scalar. I believe you want `clip(lower=5)`, i.e. if some values in the series are less than `5` replace them with `5`:

```
df['New_Column'] = (df['Column1']-df['Column2'])/df['Column2'].clip(lower=5)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you